# Creating a program that gets input from the user, and for every particular input you get a specfic output

Tags: c

So I am trying to create the program that I mentioned in the title, but there is one problem with it. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{

    char input[30];
    char array[][10] = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    printf("Enter input.\n");
    scanf("%s", input);
    if(input == array[0]){
    printf("Array 0");
    } else if(input == array[1]){
    printf("Array 1");
    } else if(input == array[2]){
    printf("Array 2");
    } else {
    printf("Incorrect.");
    }







    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for example when I enter **"One"**, it prints **"Incorrect"** instead of **"Array 0"**. The same thing happens when I input **"Two"** or "**Three"**. It doesn't work the way I intend it to be. I want it to print **"Array 0"** when I type **"One"**, **"Array 1"** when I type **"Two"**, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like comment mentions you need to use `strcmp` in order to compare strings in C. So the correct code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{

    char input[30];
    char array[][10] = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    printf("Enter input.\n");
    scanf("%s", input);
    if(strcmp(input, array[0]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Array 0");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, array[1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Array 1");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, array[2]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Array 2");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also reduce code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    char input[30];
    char array[][10] = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    printf("Enter input.\n");
    scanf("%s", input);
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        if(strcmp(input, array[x]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Array %d", x);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Incorrect.");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the statement "you cannot use `==` to compare strings in C", I'd like to mention *why* it doesn't work.

The equality operator compares 2 values, preferably of the same type and same levels of indirection, however implicit casting does allow different types of variables to be compared.

In C, strings are just `char` arrays. And [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). So essentially, when you refer to `input` and `array[i]` (where `i` is a valid index of `array`), you're actually referring to *the memory address of the start of that string*.

So, referring to `char str[10];` using `str`, will simply give you the address of `str[0]`. You can try it yourself in a simple program-

```c
int main()
{
    char str[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    printf("%p\n", str);
}
```

The above code snippet will print the address of `char str[3];`

Now when you compare the address of `input` with the *starting* address of `array[i]`, obviously, they will not be the same.

This is actually the same for any arrays, not just char arrays, you cannot compare them with `==`.

This is why you need to use `strcmp` to compare 2 strings.

```c
if (!strcmp(input, array[i]))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

`strcmp` returns 0 on a full match so you can either do an explicit `== 0` or simply `!` the `strcmp` like I've done here.

More information on `strcmp` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)